# Double Threshold Mechanism

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, thresholding

I was studying [an article](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ivan_Bruno2/publication/3939804_Optical_music_sheet_segmentation/links/0912f50f00bad5fd50000000.pdf) about optical music recognition. Somewhere in segmentation section is mentioned that

> The final step consists of isolating the note heads. This is performed by using a double threshold mechanism to obtain the results shown in Figure.

I couldn't find anything on the internet that explain what does "double threshold mechanism" means. I guess it is a very basic question. I hope someone guides me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

without knowing the context, it could be a number of things but one does not threshold unless you are making a decision (like a hypothesis test).

One example of a double threshold is getting through security at an airport. You go through the metal detector. The machine alerts or doesn’t . That is the first decision. It has a high false alarm rate because the cost of a missed detection is high. It alerts and you empty your pockets (hoping no one is stealing your laptop) and the machine still alerts.  The pat down is the second decision.  The pat down takes longer and has a higher cost but is usually more accurate, unless the gate is run by perverts, but that is something else.

There are usually more thresholds that you need to pass at the airport, but the general idea of using multiple “independent “ tests to achieve better classification performance holds.

Comment: Funny analogy. I like it!

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz is a great instructor! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that it refers to hysteresis thresholding. This is where the image is thresholded twice, at a low threshold and a high one. The connected components of the low threshold that contain at least one pixel from the high threshold are kept. This is easily implemented using the high threshold as a seed in a flood-fill operation bound by the low threshold.

The Canny edge detector uses such a threshold to select only significant edges, and at the same time prevent edges from being broken up.